# How can I move files to a specific folder using only the first 4 letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently doing an apprenticeship as an IT specialist and only have to move files in Python to a specific folder based on the first 4 letters. All letters and numbers after the first 4 digits must be ignored. I hope you can help me here. The files have different extensions, e.g. .txt, .bat, .doc

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob


    
file_source = r'C:\Users\SHall\OneDrive\Desktop\Test'
file_destination = r'D:\BTLD'

get_files = os.listdir(file_source)

for BLTD*.txt in get_files:
    os.replace(file_source,file_destination)
    shutil.move(source,destination)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example for more clear

Comment: for sure:  So i have 4 data with name: BTLD34F3.txt, BTLD38TZ.doc, BTLD98TF.prg and BTLD9002V.ppx  The program created should search for all files beginning with BTLD and move them to a designated folder.

Comment: `glob.glob('BTLD*.*')` should give you the pattern. Or whatever extension you want.

Comment: Thank you :-)  with     " for file in Path(file_source).glob('BTLD*'):" it work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need. I'm using pathlib for path manipulation instead of os and glob (same thing really).

```
import pathlib
import shutil
source_dir = pathlib.Path('./path/to/source')
target_dir = pathlib.Path('./path/to/target')
for p in source_dir.glob('BTLD*.*'):
    shutil.move(p, target_dir / p.name)
```

Edit: Automatically organize all files in folders starting with the first 4 letters of the file name. This is basic and I have only tested on some simple cases.

```
import pathlib
import shutil
source_dir = pathlib.Path('./path/to/source')
key_set = set()
for p in source_dir.glob('*.*'):
    key_set.add(p.stem[:4])
target_dir_root = pathlib.Path('./path/to/target_root')
for k in key_set:
    target_dir = target_dir_root / k
    target_dir.mkdir(exists_ok=True) # Make directories as needed
    for p in source_dir.glob(k + '*.*'):
        shutil.move(p, target_dir / p.name)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just out of interest maybe you know how it would work if I have more than one file and need to move them to a given folder eg BTLD to BTLD and GAME to GAME

Comment: Is it always with first four letters? What you essentially need is a list of 4 letter keywords for the blob. If you have such a list you do the above function in a loop. If there's no list then you'd have to make one. I would use a `set` object which I would insert the first 4 letters of all file names into. Next, loop over the the set (and create target directories). That way would automatically find and organize the files.